# moving prestashop from normal Apache site to virtual host caused prestashop to stop working

Tags: apache, prestashop, virtualhost, httpd.conf, prestashop-1.7

I had a prestashop(1.7) site located to /var/www/html (centos 8, apache web server).

I created as per most commmon instructions two virtual hosts pointed to /var/www/sites

/var/www/sites/site1/html
and
/var/www/sites/site2/html

when i place an index.html file i can see both files (rather the hello world text).
but when i copy the whole prestashop to the /var/www/sites/site1/html it does not work. i get the 500 error.

the path in the ps_shop_url is / and the domain and domain_ssl is as it was before site1.(the virtual hosts work since I can see the index pages remember?)

what else shall i configure in prestashop files in order to be able to see the shop?

thanks and regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to clear the whole /var/cache directory after migrating the files,
if this doesn't help try enabling Prestashop dev_mode (https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/configuration/)
or investigate your webserver error_log to see what's behind the error 500